# nodejs timed out on all ports when hosting on godaddy server

Tags: node.js, express, port, cpanel, listen

I've trying to run my nodejs/expressjs application on my godaddy server, but any port I use times out. I've tried using the application on my local device and it works fine. I have a snippet of my connection below.

```
var app = express();

app.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log("Listening on port " + 8080);
});
```

When I run the program through ssh, I get no errors

```
node index.js
Listening on port 8080
```

But when I go to the corresponding location in my browser, I get:

```
xxx took too long to respond.

ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

I'm pretty sure it has to do with running on the godaddy server. If anyone has experience using this service with nodejs, is there a specific port I should be using, or is there any other setup I should do?

Comment: did you specify the port in url when using your browser to connect? If you did, then pretty sure you need to have a look into firewall settings.

Comment: I did specify the port in the url. It's a shared server, so I don't think I have access to firewall settings

Comment: have a look at this: https://kr.godaddy.com/help/accessing-your-servers-firewall-console-8553

Comment: This is available only on dedicated servers. Since I am on a shared server, my manager does not have a "support" or "Firewall Console" section.

Comment: then i think this is your case : https://www.quora.com/can-we-host-node-js-application-on-godaddy-coms-shared-hosting-plan

Comment: I guess your manager blocked all ports. see [this](https://www.godaddy.com/community/Building-and-Managing-a-Website/Open-ports/td-p/5509). you need to talk to your manager, or give a try on higher number ports above 50000.

Comment: Yeah, looks like I'll have to look into something else. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a VPS with GoDaddy right? So I assume you have also root access.

SSH into your GoDaddy server as root and check if the node.js app actually listens on that port:

```
netstat -tunlp | grep 8080
```

If you see any result there for the node.js app and that port then the port is open.

By default, there should be a firewall on your server which might block most of the ports and allows only the necessary incoming traffic.

You can check if there is any rule for that port by issuing the command bellow:

```
iptables -nvL | grep 8080
```

If any result is returned, then you have to add an iptables rule to allow access to that port. There are multiple methods to do that:

- permit full access from your IP access to the server
- permit your ip to access port 8080 on the godaddy server
- permit outside world to access port 8080 on your server

You could read any iptables guy, it's pretty easy to add/edit/delete firewall rules. Most of the cPanel/WHM servers come with CSF Firewall (which is based on iptables and perl scripts).

In order to allow an ip address to your firewall (if you have CSF Firewall installed) you have to issue the following command:

```
csf -a ip-address
```

I hope that helps!